# Symfony2 - Asset function to images

Tags: symfony

I know I can use this as an asset function:

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/logo/logo.png') }}" alt="Logo">
```

But is there a way to use an asset function using another function? Like this:

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/logos/{{ dominantItem.generateLogos | lower | replace({' ': '-'}) }}.png') }}" alt="Logos">
```

Obviously the code above is not working, am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't nest twig tags like that, but you can use string concatenation to achieve what you want:

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/logos/' ~ (dominantItem.generateLogos | lower | replace({' ': '-'})) ~ '.png') }}" alt="Logos">
```

Comment: Great! I wasn't sure how to concatenate it. Super simple! Thank you for your help.